# What kind of information in cryptography is called semantic information?

Tags: terminology, literature

I have been studying cognitive cryptography from [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0268401217310241). Its definition of cognitive cryptography is:

> Cognitive cryptography is a division of cryptography
>   within which any information set can be secured using personal
>   information contained in the biometric sets of information and
>   semantic information unambiguously identifying individual features
>   of protocol participants.

What does the following part of the definition mean?

> ...semantic information unambiguously identifying individual features...

I don't understand what *semantic information* means. Specifically, what kind of information in cryptography is called *semantic information*?

I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You should be really skeptical of people who just put together two smart-person sounding words (eg. "cognitive", "smart", "cryptography", "quantum", "blockchain", "security", "future") to make a new smart-person sounding word with no formal definitions or implementation details. Especially if it seems all usage of the term comes from the same author and every paper is a whitepaper style overview. And when there is no math, algorithm, codes, or proofs in a crypto paper. It seems close to snake oil. See also id-based and attribute-based encryption which at least have Wikipedia pages.

Comment: @FutureSecurity  I exactly know what you mean. All words that you said in your comment, I have said to my professor but he told me think about how "cognitive sciences" can be applied in cryptography especially ID-based encryption. I told him how can I used this so-called new cryptography method in  ID-based  system when I can not understand the basic concept of this method. Unfortunately, this paper is published in high-rank journal. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If you sift through all the jargon, I believe all it is trying to describe is a type of encryption where the encryption keys are derived from biometric measurements such as fingerprint patterns, instead of randomly generated.

Comment: @user0410 took a copy. You can delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert but...

[Semantic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_analysis_(machine_learning)) is a concept not from cryptography but more from machine learning. The goal is for an AI to learn semantic information from some base set of inputs. For example we might train an AI to detect whether a arbitrary image contains a dog.

For the purposes of encryption an AI might learn to recognize an individual from a camera, microphone, and/or other inputs. In this case the "semantic information" would be the individual's characteristics necessary for an AI to identify that person from such external data.

Comment: Based on your comment, Can I conclude that the semantic information is one tools for artificial intelligence? I want to ask you to expand your answer and explain more about semantic analysis and its applications. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I think semantic info is a factor of AI. I think it's the descriptive terms that are used (eg. "brown eyes") and perhaps numeric characteristics as opposed to the raw input data of an image, etc... But again I'm not an expert! I can imagine how AI might help with individual encryption but I share some of the skepticism of the top comment above.

Comment: I like this part of your comment "perhaps numeric characteristics as opposed to the raw input data of an image". It's an interesting idea. Thanks again.